# Svelte Material UI How to Click on an Icon for a Textfield?

Tags: svelte, svelte-material-ui

Using Svelte and Svelte Material UI, adding an `on:click` to an `Icon` that is used inside a `Textfield` results in nothing happening when the icon is clicked in the browser:

```
<script>
    import Textfield from '@smui/textfield';
    import Icon from '@smui/textfield/icon';

    let foo;
</script>

<form>

    <Textfield bind:value={foo} label="Foo">

        <Icon 
            class="material-icons" 
            slot="trailingIcon"
            on:click={
                () => {
                    console.log('bar');
                }
            }
        >
            add
        </Icon>

    </Textfield>

</form>
```

How can I make the icon respond to an `on:click` ?

---

I did try wrapping the Icon in a `<div>` and adding the `on:click` to the div. While this worked, it yields an a11y warning that require keypress code to fix. In addition, if you use a conditional logic to print the icon, you'll get poor formatting if you set `slot="trailingIcon"` on the `Icon`, or an error if you set `slot="trailingIcon"` on the `div` instead.